# Restart a function in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, break

My code is in a while True loop.
It basically tries something like captcha.

So what I want is something like this

```
def  loop():
    toplam = 0
    global sayilar
    x = br.open(something)
    html = x.read()
    sayilar = map(str.strip,''.join(kod.findall(html)).split("\xc4\x84\xc5\x95\xc5\xa3\xc4\xb1"))
    print sayilar
    for i in sayilar:
        if i in diction:
            toplam += diction[i]
        else 
            #break the function








if __name__ == "__main__":
    giris()
    while 1:
        loop()
```

it can't find the number in dictionary it will break the function and restart the function again because function is in while loop.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to break a function?                                                                        else:                                                                                                     #break the function

Comment: Why not just use break?

Comment: Because code is not only this. This is only a part of it. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a good way to restart it.

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        # Set some exception infomation
        self.msg = arg
def  loop():
    toplam = 0
    global sayilar
    x = br.open(something)
    html = x.read()
    sayilar = map(str.strip,''.join(kod.findall(html)).split("\xc4\x84\xc5\x95\xc5\xa3\xc4\xb1"))
    print sayilar
    for i in sayilar:
        if i in diction:
            toplam += diction[i]
        else 
            raise CustomError('Kelime Dictionaryde bulunamadi')








if __name__ == "__main__":
    giris()
    while 1:
        try:
            loop()
        except CustomError, arg:
            print "Can't find in dictionary"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can literally use `break`. By using `break`, you can stop the loop immediately. You will see the use of the `return` later.

```
for i in sayilar:
    if i in diction:
        toplam += diction[i]
    else: 
        return None
        break
return True                # Anything but None will work in place of True
```

This goes the same for the `while` loop:

```
while True:    # Use True instead of 1
    loop()
    if loop() == None:            # The function call is equal to what it returned
        break
    else:
        continue                   # Optional else statement: continues loop if loop() != None
```

Comment: Code is not only this. This is only a part of it. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Also it doesn't exits. try/except is in while 1 so it retries that function.